# find the equation of a curve by integrate slope

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

A curve is such that $\frac {dy}{dx} =2\times(3x+4)^{\frac32} -6x-8$
Given that the stationary point on the curve has coordinates(-1,5). Find the equation of the curve.

I think I should integrate this dy/dx, and then substitute (-1,5) to find c.
How can I integrate this $\frac {dy}{dx}$, since it has this form "$(3x+4)^{\frac 32}$" which is not just x form only.
I have learn that I should distribute this form into $x^3+x^2 +\dots $, but this question is "to the power of $\frac 32$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you know that
$$
\int x^n\,dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C.
$$
This holds for all $n\neq -1$, not just integers. So, in particular
$$
\int x^{3/2}\,dx=\frac{x^{5/2}}{5/2}+C.
$$
Now, if you add a constant inside the power, nothing happens,
$$
\int (x+4)^{3/2}\,dx=\frac{(x+4)^{5/2}}{5/2}+C.
$$
To see this, differentiate the right-hand side, and see that you get what you should.

If you scale, something will happen. Instead of writing the rule here, I suggest that you differentiate
$$
\frac{(3x+4)^{5/2}}{5/2}+C
$$
to find out yourself what really happens.